# need IOS UI like the picture

Tags: ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2iPi.png)

[a video clip of this UI, how does it look like](http://sendvid.com/ktrleb0a)

Please Help me how can I make one, I tried to build it by UITableView and for cell UIcollectionView it works well but I can't select collection-view Cell by code ( need after select change the cell view background color )

Comment: So share the code and ask where it’s wrong or what additional u need to select it

Comment: the code is very long, Can I send it to you by email ??? Thank you

Comment: "How can I make my UI like this" is too broad. You need to tell us a _specific_ issue — what you are doing and what's happening that you didn't expect.

Comment: the specific issue is, I can select collection-view cell by code but after that, I can't change the background

Comment: Are there any library like this ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the background color of UICollectionViewCell by overriding the cell property

```
 override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isSelected {
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        } else {
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
    }
}
```

also since cell are reusable you may see some cells with blue color while scrolling as they are now reused, to avoid this override the method

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works well, but I need the select item by UIButton to select collectionView Cell and after that change the background, I did it with "collectionView.selectItem( index, animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)" but can't change the item background after selected. thank you

Comment: you mean there's a button inside cell and you want to tap on button and than it changes the background ?

Comment: No, UIButton is outside, You can see the clip in last of that I show that

Comment: i really don't understand what you're trying to achieve with button, please elaborate

Comment: I found the solution, first, I refresh the collectionView then select the view cell in collectionView.

Comment: Thank you very much